# SSL/TLS certificate - repeated domain in CN

Tags: ssl

I obtained a SSL certificate from my company's certificate authority. The Common Name value of the certificate contains a repeated domain name like so:
host.domain.domain

It should actually be:
host.domain

Not sure how this happened. Will this pose a problem when a browser tries to verify the certificate?

Comment: Yes, it will be a problem, the certificate will **never** be accepted by a correctly functioning browser. What is the contents of the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) extension? That is what really matters. The CN is only used if there is no SAN.

Comment: It happened when the CSR was created, whoever did that. You will have to repeat the process using a proper DN in a new CSR.